# Redactor ImagePosition - no custom styles

Tags: redactor

I have ImagePosition within Redactor set up, but ideally, I'd like custom settings rather than the default "none, left, right, center"

Redactor file reads:

```
{
  "buttons": ["html","formatting", "bold", "italic", "unorderedlist", 
  "orderedlist", "link", "image", "video"],
  "plugins": ["fullscreen", "video"],
  "toolbarFixed": true,
  "imagePosition": {
    "left": "image-left",
    "right": "image-right"
  }        
}
```

The above activates the ImagePosition within the Edit screen of the image but no custom styles. Cleared CP cache, no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was being a dummy. It works and does what it's meant to.

I just thought you could make your own drop parameters and classes.

You can only change the classes added, the "left, center, right" are not editable.